# django channels not working how does it work i have read docs

Tags: javascript, python, django, django-models, websocket

iam trying to use channels but not working
here is consumer.py

```
def ws_connect(message, cat_id):
    try:
        cat = Categories.objects.get(pk=cat_id)
    except Categories.DoesNotExist:
        pass
    Group('cat-1').add(message.reply_channel)


def ws_diconnect(message, cat_id):
    try:
        cat = Categories.objects.get(pk=cat_id)

    except Categories.DoesNotExist:
        pass
    Group('cat-1').discard(message.reply_channel)
```

and this is routing.py :

```
channel_routing = [
    route('websocket.receive', ws_connect, path=r'^/liveupdate/(?P<cat_id>\d+)/'),
    route("websocket.disconnect", ws_diconnect, path=r'^/liveupdate/(?P<cat_id>\d+)/'),
]
```

this is signals.py :

```
@receiver(post_save, sender=Tender)
def send_update(sender, instance, created, raw, using, **kwargs):
    print '>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>', instance, '2', raw, '3', using, '4', kwargs
    data = json.dumps(
        {'ministry': 'hisham',})
    Group('cat-1').send({'tender': data,})
    print 'Done'
```

and here is javascript :

```
<script type="application/javascript">
    var ws_scheme = window.location.protocol == "https:" ? "wss" : "ws";
    alert(ws_scheme +"://" + window.location.host + "/liveupdate/1/");
    var socket = new WebSocket(ws_scheme +"://" + window.location.host + "/liveupdate/1/");
    socket.onmessage = function(e) {
    alert(e.data);
};
    socket.onopen = function() {
        console.log("Connected to  socket");
    };
    socket.onclose = function() { console.log("Disconnected to  socket"); }

</script>
```

when iam tring to save tender signal fire but nothing in browser 
i.e no alert of data
what is the wrong with my code
any ideas

here is my folders:
[image]

Comment: Have you added channel app and asgi in installed apps ?

Comment: @Anurag  INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'Customeauth',
    'Register',
    'channels',
    'django_countries',
]

Comment: i have added photo of folders in project take alook @Anurag

Comment: i moved consumers.py to Register but the same

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of **websocket.receive** use **websocket.connect**. Receive is used when client is sending data to server.

```
route('websocket.connect', ws_connect, path=r'^/liveupdate/(?P<cat_id>\d+)/'),
```

When are you sending data instead of tender use **text** as a Key.

```
Group('cat-1').send({'text': data,})
```

Comment: Trying 1 min please

Comment: Thank you so much you made my day 